# Best mix of aspnet deployment tools

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, aspnet-compiler

I know how many questions have been asked around this, but I still can't figure out the answer to my question.

I need to deploy an ASP.NET 4.0 site, and I want to do something like this:

1. Get latest version og the entire solution - a website and a couple class projects that are used by the webapp (I am doing this already using CCNet- not a problem)
2. Build and deploy in debug config to a test site
3. Build and deploy in a release configuration to a staging site
4. If everything looks fine on the staging site, I'll run a script that deploys the release build staging site, to 7-8 similar sites used by different customers on the same server. In the future this will be on another server.

There is MSDeploy (webdeploy 2.0), aspnet_compiler, MSBuild, Powershell (my weapon of choice..) and propably more ...  I am not 100% sure what to use where?

I would love to mimick the "only deploy files needed to run the site" from the Vs2010 GUI assisted deployment, and I'd love to have the possibility of not touching some existing folders in the websites that we deploy to.

I feel like I should use MSDeploy a lot ... but I find it pretty hard to GET.  I'm reading away in IIS.NET and I've heard the Scott Hanselman/Jon Arild Tørresdal podcast. I am not 100% sure where to start ... and I'm not a MSBuild expert, so Powershell is looking pretty good to me.  But I feel I'm missing out on the right tools by going that way ...

What tool would you use in which step??

Answer (score -1):

According to me, MSDeploy is build to achieve all of your needs with much more control. MSDeploy is the product of IIS team and it's far more feature rich.

Answers to your questions
Considerations: Svn as Source control, MSDeploy for deployment

1. You can use SVN Command line tool to get latest version of your source code in some temp directory and build it using MSBuild command line tool. Then you can create a Deployment Package or a Publish Content Package which can be deployed to specific environment. I am currently working on a project which can basically create a deployment package independent of the environment, means the pacakge can be deployed to any stage/test/live environment. Sample for creating a deployment package is...

   msbuild C:\Projects\NimBuildDeployTestApp\NimBuildDeployWebApp/NimBuildDeployWebApp.csproj /t:package /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageLocation=C:\Temp\DeployPackage\NimTestWebApp.zip /p:EnablePackageProcessLoggingAndAssert=true
2. Use MSDeploy command line tool to deploy the package as below

   msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=packagelocation -dest:CONFIGURABLE_ACCORDING_TO_YOUR_NEEDS
3. User Step 2 to build the solution in Release mode using MSBUILD and configure the dest parameter in msdeploy.
4. If everything seems fine on your staging server, run the deploymentToLive.batch file which will deploy a particular PublishContent/package on your live server. Execute 7 msdeploy scripts in same batch file or else use DFS (which is far more complex solution)

MSDeploy is definitely the way to go. One thing that you may consider is having a deployment package ready which can be deployed onto any environment of yours. What I mean by that is your web.config file won't be similar for all the envrionments, and hence create a deployment package which contains web.confif file for all the environments. Refer to my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351891/msdeploy-all-configuration-config-files-in-one-package)

Hope this helps and gives you confidence in moving forward to automate your deployment process